# How to enable typing for non-english characters in a HTML textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, fonts, arabic

I have installed Arabic web fonts on my website. But when I type anything in a Textarea I see English characters. When I Copy Arabic characters from another website and paste into textarea, they appear perfectly. 
How can I insert arabic character directly from my keyboard?

Thanks,
Zubair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the Keyboard language. Depending on the operating system you must find how to set your keyboard input from standard US to Arabic. On Windows 8 you go to 
**Control Panel -> Change input methods -> Add a language** on Windows 7 and Vista check out the following [How to change your keyboard layout](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258824). Also I am assuming you have included
`<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for replying, 
So every user that visits my website must change his keyboard to Arabic? I am looking for a way to type Arabic without changing keyboard layout. There are few websites already doing it, I can't figure out how are they doing it.

Comment: try this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
... you can play around with dir="rtl" and dir="ltr", I am not sure how to write in Arabic

Comment: In order to write in a specific language you need to change the diacritics of the keyboard. Or there might be some JavaScript or other scripting language that implemented the functionality of converting Latin letters into Arabic when somebody types a Key.

Comment: That should work for me. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

To enter Arabic characters on *your* keyboard, you need to use a keyboard layout (keyboard driver) that allows such typing or to use some other (system-dependent) input method.

But as you probably mean how to make it possible to your *visitors* to enter Arabic text, that answer is not that useful.

Generally, you can expect that people who can and wish to type Arabic text are using devices and software that make it possible to them to do so. You do not need to do anything except 1) the usual thing of using UTF-8 encoding for the page and declaring it (or, if that is not possible, at least using `accept-charset=utf-8` for the `form` element) and 2) the special thing of setting `dir=rtl` on the `textarea` element *if* it is expected to contain (dominantly) text in Arabic letters or another right-to-left writing system.

However, it is possible that a user who can and wishes to write in Arabic letters is using a non-Arabic keyboard layout, e.g. a US keyboard at a hotel. He might even have no way of changing keyboard layout. You may therefore consider using one of the following techniques (not mutually exclusive, but using both might be confusing):

1) Set up a virtual keyboard on your page, i.e. a set of elements that look like keyboard keys and act so that when you click on one of them, the character shown in it gets appended to the textarea. This is relatively straighforward and does not take much time to code for a relatively small alphabet like the basic Arabic letters. Many sites use such techniques.

2) Set up handlers for keyboard events so that e.g. when a user presses a key that normally produces the letter “a”, your code intercepts it and inserts, say, the Arabic letter ʾalif instead. This is somewhat more complicated due to differences between browsers in handling keyboard events. The main problem, however, is that you cannot know the type of the keyboard used. The user might have a keyboard layout that lacks all Latin letters at least in the primary positions. Moreover, the user might want to type a word in Latin letters, e.g. a proper name in the midst of Arabic text.