# How to convert English text into Arabic in a PHP app?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a sports community application.

- In which every user can post anything(text,link,images) related to any sports.
- Everything is working fine but now I need the posted text in Arabic language, currently it's in English.
- Is there any idea that every post that any user type in textarea must be in Arabic and insert in MySQL and fetches from there without any problem, I am using CodeIgniter.
- I have converted all the hardcoded text into Arabic using language library, but now every single word that use type in text area for post must be typed in Arabic.

I have made some changes in the header file like below:

```
<html lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar">
```

Comment: You want automagic translation from English to Arabic...? Or am I greatly misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: I think he means "restrict the entered posts to Arabic characters"

Comment: i want every post that user type in text field would type in arabic lang.

Comment: So what happens if a user *does* type in "English"?

Answer (score -2):

This is due to your keyboard language in your OS, this question is a duplication of [this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089425/how-to-enable-typing-for-non-english-characters-in-a-html-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089425/how-to-enable-typing-for-non-english-characters-in-a-html-textarea)

If this does not help, you may try to change your php files' encoding types to an Arabic encode, you may do  that by opening your view file in notepad++, and changing the encoding from the encoding menu -> character sets -> Arabic and choose either ISO / OEM / or WINDOWS

This will make sure characters typed/posted to/displayed are all correct

Hope this helps

Comment: its not duplicate i have already seen these type of posted question

Comment: OK sorry,if you feel it is not a duplication. So does that nto fix your issue? The person typing needs to have their keyboard language set to Arabic, also edited the answer now with one more thing to care for, please have a read above

Answer (score -2):

> I am arab too

So since this problem repeats too many times for us, RTL righters
First you should use UTF-8 as encoding for all your files (views, language, controllers, ...)...

Then you may have to use `'string'` instead of `"string"`

Comment: please copy past some text from your files so I can help out

Comment: No, i mean some of your arabic text examples, and please tell me if the arabic text comes partially or fully from a database?